# Telelogic Synergy equivalent of svn blame?

Tags: cm-synergy

Is there an equivalent in Synergy to the `blame` command in Subversion?

I'd like to be able to see, for a given version of a file, the originating change request or task for each line of that file.

I'm using Synergy version 6.5.4105.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synergy has no official equivalent of `blame` in it's command set (hopefully later they have one).

Although [this page](http://better-scm.berlios.de/comparison/scm-comparison.xml) speculates, that it is possible via their scripting language.

Comment: I should be possible with some serious scripting. But it would require quite a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

Parasoft C++Test provides a 'Show author at line' menu option in Eclipse, that works when the CM system is configured for CMSynergy. It provides the date & author & comment, but not the task id! Versions I'm using are:

Eclipse 3.5.2 (with CDT)
 CppTest 7.3.2
 CMSynergy 7.1

Best regards,
Aaron